# VS 2015 Crash on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, event-viewer

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 which sometimes crashes when I try to build/rebuild/clean the solution. I am working on a WPF application with .NET 4.6.1. If I look into Event Viewer there are available the following errors:

1:

[image: First Exception]

2:

[image]

What can cause this kind of errors? In my opinion it is a framework bug. However, can be avoided? Does anyone face the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the call stack we can see NUnit is leading to the crash.

Thus, while VS starts up, go to Extensions and remove any NUnit bits (VS adapter for example), and then try again.

Comment: The Nunit package was the problem. I've updated NUnit nuget to version 3.0.0 and now it works. Thank you!